# C++ Using a sequence of values from 'for' loop one at a time in a consecutive order within another function

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, indexing, reference

I would like to use a 'for' loop (OR anything that works for that matter) to generate a sequence of values.

I iterate many times and need to use values from the loop (OR anything that works) one at a time in a consequent manner. This values are used to represent 'time' value in an equation  for population growth. Ultimately I am to have a chart representing solutions for calculations where 'time'is 1,2,3,4...60.

My question is: how to make the equation "value = a * exp(k * t)" consider t = 'time'as a new consecutive value from a vector that 'loop' generated ?

EDIT: I will try to clarify the set up - both reset and update act as iterations. In this specific case reset runs once and update runs n times. What I need is to use a consequent value of 'time' each iteration of update i.e. first time update runs the value of t = first value within the vector, second time update runs t = second value within the vector etc.

void ExponentialGrowth::reset() {update();}

void ExponentialGrowth::update() {value = a * exp(k * t); }

Comment: Store the values from the initial `for` loop in a table - or am I missing the point?

Comment: If `time` is 1,2,3,4,...60, why do you need to calculate it?

Comment: I need to calculate value not the time.

Answer (score 3):

if t is integer type (0 to 60)

```
#include "math.h"

int a = 1;
int k = 2;
for(int time = 0; time < 60; ++time){
    int value = a * exp(k * time);
}
```

if you have to pass the size juste make a function

```
void func(int _start, int _end){
    int a = 1;
    int k = 2;
    for(int i = _start; i <= _end; ++i){
        int value = a * exp(k * i);
    }
}
```

Comment: In C++, the `<cmath>` header would be preferred, along with `std::exp`.

Comment: When you say size do you mean just as in 60 ? Because I need 60 different values.